# Running multiple servers in a single command terminal instance

Tags: shell, webpack, command-line, command, command-prompt

I have 3 folders:

[image]

Each folder runs a completely different type of server.

api = webpack server, app = angular server and game = gulp server

Each folder requires me to run a different command to run it's server in a separate command instance which is troublesome for my users. They have to have 3 command instances up at the same time which is confusing for them.

Is there a way I can run the following commands within each folder from a single command instance?

`api` needs to run = `npm start`

`app` needs to run = `ng serve`

`game` needs to run = `gulp watch server`

I can't find any resources whatsoever to help in this precise scenerio - which is making me think it's not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) for a similar usecase.

Install npm-run-all:

```
npm i npm-run-all
```

The script block within package.json could look like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "api": "npm start",
    "app": "ng serve",
    "game": "gulp watch server",
    "all": "npm-run-all --parallel api app game",
},
```

Note the parameter `--parallel`.

The command to run:

```
npm run all
```